# Unable to load CSS using grails rendering plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, pdf-generation, rendering, asset-pipeline

I have a grails 2.4.3 app that uses the rendering 1.0.0 plugin and asset-pipeline:1.9.9.  I can successfully generate a PDF from a GSP, but

- There is no styling, so it look like garbage
- Every CSS reference in the GSP causes `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` to show up in the logs

When I comment out all CSS references, there are no errors, but it still looks like garbage.  I believe the `stream closed` problem is due to the XHTML parser not being able to load the CSS file.  The CSS references look like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Invoicer/assets/invoicer.css?compile=false"  />
```

When I load up that URL in the browser, the CSS file is successfully returned and displayed.

I'm also using Spring Security and thought that maybe it was an authentication issue.  I removed all of the filters in `Config.groovy`, so it looks like this

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/**':                          ['permitAll']
]
```

but that did not help.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After re-reading the documentation, I noticed this:

> The rendering engine resolves all relative links relative to the
>   grails.serverURL config property.

I figured `serverURL` would have been set automatically, but it wasn't.  I set

`grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:9090/${appName}"`

in Config.groovy *as well as*

`grails.server.port.http = 9090`

in BuildConfig.groovy.  It also appears that they layout engine is not getting called, so I had to manually pull in the CSS files:

`<asset:stylesheet src="invoicer.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer, but it's ugly.  I noticed that specifying the full path to the CSS indeed did work:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:9090/Invoicer/assets/bootstrap.css?compile=false"  />`

Now, since I'm using asset-pipeline, I have to make asset-pipeline use an absolute URL in Config.groovy:

`grails.assets.url = "http://localhost:9090/Invoicer/assets/"`

Not pretty, but it will work for now.